# Object texture not sticking to object

Tags: materials, shaders

I have a simple sphere with a shader material that is meant to look like the sun. The problem is that this texture feels like it is attached to the centre of the world and you can clearly see it stretch towards the centre which is not what I want it to do.
Here is a gif of what I am talking about.

Any advise on how to fix this?

Edit: It also seems like moving the vertices in the UV editing tab does not change the placement of the texture. Moving and/or scaling the UV vertices has no effect whatsoever.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you give us more detail on how the texture is constructed and applied to the object? It almost looks like it was built in Shader Nodes using a bit of arithmetic computed relative to the world origin

Comment: @NeverConvex I've edited the post with the image for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add UV coordinates to the *Image* and *Noise* textures.  This will cause the texture to stay in place as you rotate the sun.  Add the nodes in the frame.

[image: Add the nodes in the frame]

Comment: Agreed - without a connected Texture Coordinate, Image Textures will use _UV_ coordinates by default, and Procedural (ie. noise) Textures use _Generated_ coordinates by default. To keep the texture mapped to the object the way you intend, add a Texture Coordinate node and use UV for both, as Marty suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solved the issue. Is there a reason you've changed the input of the bump node to be the alpha of the image instead of the color? It doesn't look like using the alpha has any effect on the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Your image texture is set to equirectangular instead of flat.

Equirectangular Images are mostly used for world background/hdri textures.

[Unwrap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/index.html) your sphere if you haven't already and use the UV output of a Texture coordinate node to control where your image is placed on the model.

[image]

Comment: Agreed this is (one of the) problem(s). I'll only add that _Image Textures_ do not have an Equirectangular option - only _Environment Textures_ do. Therefore, delete the _Environment_ Texture and add an _Image texture_ instead.